# Why should we fetch in object?

Tags: php, database, arrays, object

I'm not referring to a particular database driver or so but we, as PHP developer, have always had the choice to use either arrays or object as return type of a database query.

So for example we could access the column "title" with either `$array['title']` or `$object->title`.

For example mysql PHP built-in functions `mysql_fetch_assoc()` and `mysql_fetch_object()` give this choice.

I noticed that the object-way (as I'm gonna call it) is much worse:

- You cannot specify table names that contains special chars such as `.` or `-` and use them with objects.
- Object are usually heavier than arrays
- Object doesn't have all the cool functions to manage them as arrays do
- Arrays better explain the table structure rather then property chaining.

There are few other little things about object vs array war regarding database results but these are the main ones.

Why do people even take the object-way as choice?

Comment: "Arrays better explain the table structure" — I don't want to care about the table structure when I'm putting data into my views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You **can** specify table names that contains special chars such as . or -
- Object are more flexible than arrays
- Object have all the cool functions that you can imagine to manage them, you just have to write a few of them
- Arrays don't cleanly express relationships between tables, object mapping does.

Comment: How would you access them as object? `$object->post.id`? `$object->post-id`? I don't think so. This is a parse error.

Comment: Arrays are table viewed by default. `$array[0][3]` refers for example to the first row and the 3 column. Arrays are seen, pretty much in every programming language, as tables.

Comment: Flexibility - show me how you'd set up a piece of code to autosave a modified array back to its database table when the script terminated, or you unset it... I can do that easily with an object destructor

Comment: arrays (as implemented in PHP) don't exist natively in most programming languages

Comment: You win this time! ... Just kidding. Didn't knew all this stuff. Thanks very much for enlightening me.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly use it because `$user->name` is a lot easier on the eyes than `$user['name']`